# Laravel 5 - Eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model, eloquent, relationship

I have three tables as below:

```
 ------------------------------
| users  | projects  | clients |
|--------|-----------|-------- |
| id     | id        | id      |
| name   | client_id | name    |
|        | user_id   |         |
|        | name      |         |
 ------------------------------
```

So basically the relationship is like:

*User hasMany Project

Project belongsTo Client*

My question is: 
**How can I get all clients of a user using eloquent?**

Seems like I cannot user hasManyThrough method as there are no project_id in clients table.

So what I wish to achieve is :

```
foreach($users as $user)
     foreach($user->clients as $client) //HOW TO SET UP THIS RELATION?
         foreach($client->projects($user)->get() as $project)
```

Comment: you must have a relation between user and project models in laravel

Comment: I know I could get the user projects directly (User hasMany Project), but I wish to get them through the Client Model, which mean even a client is not belong to the user, as long as the client's project is belongs to the user, then the the user are able to get the Project through Client.

Comment: Did you try `hasManyThrough` relationship?

Comment: @JamalAbdulNasir For now the relationship is like `User hasMany Projects, Project belongsTo Client`, I think `hasManyThrough` is only applicable on one to many relation, since there are no `project_id` in `Client` table.

Comment: and what is the realation of projects to users?

Comment: @JamalAbdulNasir Project belongsTo User

Answer (score 0):

```
    $users = User::with('projects')->get();
    
    // organize cleints' project and add for each user  
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        // order projects by client_id
        $projects = Collect($user->projects->toArray());
        $clients = $projects->groupBy('client_id');

        // keep projects data in 'projects' index 
        $temp = array();
        foreach($clients as $client => $projects){
            $temp[$client] = array('projects' => $projects);
        }

        // add clinets data for each user
        $user['clients'] = $temp;
    }

    // output
    foreach($users as $user)
        foreach($user->clients as $client)
            foreach($client['projects'] as $project)
                echo 'user-'.$project['user_id'].', clinet-'.$project['client_id'].', project-'.$project['name'].'<br>';
```

Above code generated this output for me:

[image]